# What differences are between behavioralism and functionalism?

Tags: methodology, behaviorism, history-of-psychology

Is it correct that behavioralism and functionalism are similar in that they both treat brain or something else as a blackbox, and are only concerned about the relationships between inputs and outputs for the blackbox?

What are their differences?

Was behavioralism influenced by functionalism?